# Can you add custom html tags to Jekyll?

Tags: html, perl, templates, markdown, jekyll

I'd like to generate some template pages using `Jekyll` which will then be used by a `Perl` script making use of the `HTML::Template` `Perl` module. Is it possible to get Jekyll to leave HTML::Template's tags alone and just ignore them completely?

For example:

```
<tr>             <td>Name:               </td>  <td><TMPL_VAR NAME=NAME> </td> </tr>
<tr class="alt"> <td>Email:              </td>  <td><TMPL_VAR NAME=EMAIL></td> </tr>
```

I want the page to get rendered as a .html file with the `<TMPL_VAR NAME=...>` bits left alone, later on a backend `Perl` script would make use of this file as a template file and would fill in the spots where the `<TMPL_VAR NAME=...>` bits are.

Comment: Can you guys explain why you've down voted this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what I learned from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11321037/33204) I asked & answered on stackoverflow, these appear to be your 3 options. One of which [@Alan W. Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102401/alan-w-smith) stumbled onto as well in an answer to this question.

**Option #1:** - `HTML::Template` has a switch called `vanguard_compatibility_mode`...from the perldocs

> vanguard_compatibility_mode - if set to 1 the module will expect to see s that
>   look like %NAME% in addition to the standard syntax.  Also sets die_on_bad_params => 0.
>   If you're not at Vanguard Media trying to use an old format template don't worry about
>   this one.  Defaults to 0.

**Option #2** - `HTML::Template` also supports embedding the template tags in comment blocks so that your code is HTML compliant, like so: `<!-- TMPL_NAME NAME=FNAME -->`

Again from the perldocs:

> If you're a fanatic about valid HTML and would like your templates to conform to valid
>   HTML syntax, you may optionally type template tags in the form of HTML comments. This
>   may be of use to HTML authors who would like to validate their templates' HTML syntax
>   prior to HTML::Template processing, or who use DTD-savvy editing tools.
>
> `<!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=PARAM1 -->`

This 2nd option didn't work originally for me until I set the `die_on_bad_params => 0` for the constructor.

**Option #3:** Change the name of your [Jekyll](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) file from `.md` (markdown) to `.html` (vanilla html). This option get's around Jekyll's use of [ReXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) for it's XML parser. I'm not sure but if you switched from using [ReXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) to [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/), I think that too would get around this issue, but I'm not entirely sure you can even reconfigure [Jekyll](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) in this manner.

**Conclusion:** Ultimately I think **Option #2** is the best one to use, given it doesn't limit your ability to use `.md` files within [Jekyll](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the HTML (both standard and your Perl HTML::Template sets) as is by creating your source pages with a .html extension. When you do that, jekyll (as of 0.11.2 at least) won't mess with the source HTML. You can still use YAML front matter and drop in liquid tags. For example, this would work as a source file with a .html extension.

```
---
layout: default
title: This is the post title
categories: ["miscellaneous"]
---

{{ page.title }}

<table>
<tr>             <td>Name:  </td>  <td><TMPL_VAR NAME=NAME> </td> </tr>
<tr class="alt"> <td>Email: </td>  <td><TMPL_VAR NAME=EMAIL></td> </tr>
</table>
```

From there, you can pass to your secondary processing with your HTML::Template tags intact.