# Can the Perl Module HTML::Template use other syntaxes besides <TMPL_VAR NAME=...>?

Tags: html, perl, templates

I'm trying to make use of the `Perl` module `HTML::Template` and according to the docs it says  you can use `HTML` comments instead of greater-than/less-thans around its markup but it isn't working for me.

From the perldoc for HTML::Template

> If you're a fanatic about valid HTML and would like your templates to conform to valid
>   HTML syntax, you may optionally type template tags in the form of HTML comments. 
>   This may be of use to HTML authors who would like to validate their templates' 
>   HTML syntax prior to HTML::Template processing, or who use DTD-savvy editing tools.
>
> ```
>    <!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=PARAM1 -->
> ```

When I try this I get these messages in my apache logs:

> [Tue Jul 03 19:24:23 2012] [error] [client ::1] HTML::Template : Attempt to set
>   nonexistent parameter 'fname' - this parameter name doesn't match any declarations 
>   in the template file : (die_on_bad_params => 1) at /var/www/cgi-bin/form.cgi line 90,
>   referer: .... getcontactinfo.html

Setting the option `die_on_bad_params => 0` to the `HTML::Template->new` method seems to allow the comment format of the template names to work, can anyone confirm that this is the correct way to accomplish this?

**EDIT #1**

Here is some of the actual code:

**From my .html template file**

```
<tbody>
<tr>             <td>First Name:         </td>  <td><!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=FNAME -->           </td> </tr>
<tr>             <td>Name:               </td>  <td><!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=NAME -->           </td> </tr>
<tr class="alt"> <td>Email:              </td>  <td><!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=EMAIL -->          </td> </tr>
<tr>             <td>Affiliation:        </td>  <td><!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=AFFILIATION -->    </td> </tr>
```

**From my .cgi script**

```
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => '/var/www/html/acknowledge.html', die_on_bad_params => 0);
$template->param(FNAME          => $firstName);
$template->param(NAME           => $firstName . " " . $lastName);
$template->param(EMAIL          => $email);
$template->param(AFFILIATION    => $affiliation);
```

Comment: Please present your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 2 methods I've found thus far are the following:

1 - HTML::Template has a switch called vanguard_compatibility_mode...from the perldocs

> vanguard_compatibility_mode - if set to 1 the module will expect to see s that
>   look like %NAME% in addition to the standard syntax.  Also sets die_on_bad_params => 0.
>   If you're not at Vanguard Media trying to use an old format template don't worry about
>   this one.  Defaults to 0.

2 - HTML::Template also supports embedding the template tags in comment blocks so that your code is HTML compliant, like so: `<!-- TMPL_NAME NAME=FNAME -->`

Again from the perldocs:

> If you're a fanatic about valid HTML and would like your templates to conform to valid
>   HTML syntax, you may optionally type template tags in the form of HTML comments. This
>   may be of use to HTML authors who would like to validate their templates' HTML syntax
>   prior to HTML::Template processing, or who use DTD-savvy editing tools.
>
> `<!-- TMPL_VAR NAME=PARAM1 -->`

This 2nd option didn't work originally for me until I set the `die_on_bad_params => 0` for the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a paramater named "fname" anywhere in your code, so I don't understand the error message. Maybe the code you posted is not the complete code?

Regarding die_on_bad_params: Yes, setting it to 0 is the way to solve this, and I personally always set it to 0 and have never understood why one would need this option anyway.
In my HTML::Template::Compiled (similar alternative to HTML::Template) module I have never implemented it.

Comment: Yes I truncated the example code in the question, I've added the missing lines so that it's more clear.

Comment: Thanks that's kind of what I figured out too looking through the code of the HTML::Template Perl module but I figured I'd pose the question to see if I was reading it right.

Comment: well, _if_ you have a template parameter fname, then HTML::Template shouldn't complain at all.